# Sanity Deployment in Azure Pipeline

Tags: reactjs, azure-pipelines, sanity

I'm trying to deploy my sanity react app, here's the repo:
https://github.com/sebastian-meckovski/sanity-admin-area

here's my yml file:

```
trigger:
- main
- feature/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
 SANITY_AUTH_TOKEN: $(SanityDeployAPIToken)
 SANITY_STUDIO_PROJECT_BASEPATH: /studio

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.x'
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      cd src/Studio
      npm install -g @sanity/cli
      npm install
      sanity deploy
```

been using this article for help: https://blog.novacare.no/deploy-sanity-studio-with-azure-devops/

I'm getting this error in cmdline in azure:

> Your project has not been assigned a studio hostname.
> To deploy your Sanity Studio to our hosted Sanity.Studio service,  you will need one. Please enter the part you want to use.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sanity Deployment in Azure Pipeline

That is because you would be asked to choose a unique hostname for your Studio when you first deploy sanity.

This is a pop-up verification window that needs to interact with our developers.

But the hosted agent is in the service mode instead of Interactive. Please check the docuement [Azure Pipelines agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service) for some more details.

In this case, the verification window will not pop-up for the hosted agent. That is the reason why you get the error the project has not been assigned a studio hostname.

To resolve this issue, you need to **create your private agent and set it as Interactive mode**.

[Self-hosted Linux agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops)

Or you could just **deploy it from your local with command line**, so that you could assign a studio hostname.

**Of course**, a more complete solution would be to have Sanity pre-specify the hostname somewhere (a json-like file) and then read it when deploying Sanity without specifying it during the process. But I'm not a Sanity expert and it's not clear if there is such a way.